# how to convert markdown file to pdf conserving the template defined in a word document

Tags: pdf, markdown

I have a java script which generates a markdown file , I need to convert this file to pdf with the preserve of a template defined in word document
how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandoc's [`--reference-doc` option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--reference-doc) to go from markdown to word:

```
pandoc --reference-doc template.docx input.md -o output.docs
```

But then you still need to fire up word to go to PDF, there's no way around that if you want to use the word template. Alternatively, you can use pandoc (or other tools) to go from markdown to PDF via HTML or LaTeX, see [creating a PDF](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf).

Comment: This creates a word document but without conserving the template declared as a reference

Comment: The template file needs to use the same formatting styles as pandoc. From the docs: "For best results, the reference docx should be a modified version of a docx file produced using pandoc."

Comment: I have a specefic template that needs to be followed to generate the pdf file , how can I do this please ?